# Allow migrating if you have enough rep on either the source or target sites

Tags: feature-request, migration

I have >3000 rep on SO, but <3000 on all the rest.  That means I can mark questions on SO as "belong on SF/SU/Meta" but I can't marked questions on the other sites as "belongs on SO".

The amount of rep I have on SO means that I can be trusted to determine what belongs there.  I think it should work both ways.  That is, if I have enough rep in SO, I should be able to migrate questions **to** SO, and not only from.

Answer (score 2):

You can always add a comment, or flag the question for moderator attention.

Answer (score 2):

Your rep on the source site is what is important because it is the people with enough rep on the source site who have the responsibility to say "This does NOT belong here" and then say it belongs elsewhere.

Not having the amount of rep on source does (and should) preclude you from making those types of calls about getting rid of something. Your rep on the destination is not important because this is designed to a "push" system and not a "pull" system where the destination site (and it's trusted users) can say "gimme that".

Comment: I will agree that we do have a 'push' system, but I does tend to result in lots of junk being tossed to other sites when it should have been closed.  I think a persons rep on the destination site should factor in to the question migration some how.

Answer (score 0):

Flagging the question for moderator attention is getting sort of stupid. I can only imagine how much spamming the mods are getting now that superuser has gone live and there's no specific "flag for move" option.

The vote-to-move option should just require less rep no matter what.