# Only allow someone to “vote to migrate” if they have over a given rep on the target site

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Require minimum reputation on the target site for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74053/require-minimum-reputation-on-the-target-site-for-migration)

How can someone that has not used a given target site know if it is a good site to migrate a question to?

Therefore why not require a user to have over 500 rep on the target site before they can vote to migrate a question to that site?

See Also

- [Require more than simple majority of close votes to migrate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89242/require-more-than-simple-majority-of-close-votes-to-migrate)
- [Allow a question closed as “of topic” to still be voted on to be migrated to another site.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97733/allow-a-question-closed-as-of-topic-to-still-be-voted-on-to-be-migrated-to-anot)

Comment: Why do you mind about this? It's just a "suggestion" and moderator does consider if it's right site to migrate question to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would limit migrations so incredibly severely in practice that we might as well stop migrating questions anywhere.

For the record, it is *exceedingly* rare for users to have multiple high rep accounts in the network.

Totally not workable.

Comment: That way I said 500 rep (not 3000) on the other site, just how low do we have to go with rep on the target site so as not to limit migrating too much?

Comment: @ian it is simply the wrong approach; a few months from now we will get to letting the receiving site approve incoming migrations, but until then this would do massive harm.

Comment: "receiving site approve incoming migrations" is the better solution