# How can I re-open a closed question, but make the re-open be for another Stack Exchange site

Tags: feature-request, questions, vote-to-close, closed-questions, off-topic

I frequently see questions that I or others have asked that get closed.

Sometimes (especially with the increasing number of Stack Exchange sites), it would be appropriate to transfer them to another Stack Exchange site (this for ones that are already closed).

Example: I asked "How can I focus and concentrate at work?" on 'The Workplace'. It was closed. It now seems like moving it to 'Personal Producivity' would be good. Now it's closed, there's no obvious way for me to request it be re-opened "on another site".

I understand that we don't want to 'dump' questions into another site ([Allow a question closed as “off topic” to still be voted on to be migrated to another site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97733/allow-a-question-closed-as-off-topic-to-still-be-voted-on-to-be-migrated-to-an)), but I find our solution really isn't that great, and it continually frustrates me.

I am always wishing for a 're-open and move to another site' link. Maybe it could require more votes than others to have the move happen?

Comment: I completely agree! I have seen this problem as well, and it needs to be properly addressed.

Comment: Usually if the moderators at the target site and the person asking the question both agree with the move, a moderator at the source site can be flagged to migrate the question

Comment: Did you look for duplicates? There's slim chance a question will be migrated if there's a ton of similar questions at the target site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just flag the question asking for it to be moved to a different site if it's not available as a 3k-rep migration option. Take care that some beta sites may not accept migrations until they've been active for a while (I'm not sure exactly how long) and their scope is well-defined.

Comment: **Whether or not the site will accept your proposed migration is entirely up to the moderators of the proposed target site.** One of the reasons you flag it for moderation attention is because the migrating moderator is expected to communicate with the moderators on the target site to see if the question is acceptable for their site. Their decision is final—if they say no, the question dies a sad death on the original site.