# How is reason for closing a question determined?

Tags: support, close-reasons, faq-proposed

I just voted as the 4<sup>th</sup> person to close [a question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182228/place-to-team-up-with-coders) and wanted to select the `off topic -> belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com` option. I accidentally left the radio button on `off topic` instead of selecting the radio button `belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com`.

But since I saw that the 3 people before me all voted to migrate to Programmers-SE, I thought that the question would still be moved to Programmers-SE. However, after the fifth close vote, I see the question isn't migrated to Programmers-SE...

Questions: has my higher rep and/or higher flag-weight on SO resulted in the fact that the question wasn't migrated? If not, how *is* the reason for closing a question determined then?

Comment: It was a good thing you didn't cast the vote you intended - that question would have been closed on Programmers as well.

Comment: @ChrisF, well, I wasn't sure if it belonged there, but since I don't frequent Programmers-SE, _and_ the other 3 before me all voted to migrate it, I thought it'd be a safe bet... :)

Comment: Users of Stack Overflow are notoriously (among some people) bad judges of what makes a good or bad Programmers question. Sometimes a bad question is just a bad question

Comment: @ChrisF, yeah, I think I'll go read the FAQ on Programmers-SE to see what's on- and off-topic there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Normally a simple majority 3:2 is required to determine the close reason (there is a special case of three reasons with 2:2:1 votes but that's not important here).

However, for migration there needs to be at least 4 votes to migrate the question and that at least one of the questions tags exists on the target site. This means that if there is a reasonable doubt over whether the migration is valid or not the question **doesn't** get migrated. There have been a spate of bad migrations that required this change.

Comment: Ah, that sounds more than reasonable. Thanks for clearing that up Chris.

Comment: According to [this answer from Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74053/require-minimum-reputation-on-the-target-site-for-migration/79707#79707) there's also a tag related requirement to allow migrations to happen, but as far as I can see that wouldn't have been a problem for this particular question.

Comment: That question wouldn't have belonged on Programmers anyway, or not?

Comment: @Bobby - I think it's too chatty to be a good question - [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) seems to apply to it, but it also isn't on [this list](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Comment: @Bobby - no it wouldn't (see my comment on this question and on the SO question itself).

Comment: @ChrisF: Whoops, missed the comments.

Comment: Just curious, what happens in the special case of 2:2:1?

Comment: @jadarnel27 I think the last close reason that had 2 votes wins...