# Closed as off-topic... moved to Programmers?

Tags: discussion, support, migration, off-topic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is reason for closing a question determined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112746/how-is-reason-for-closing-a-question-determined)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713407/is-this-the-correct-approach-to-an-oop-design-structure-in-php?noredirect=1) was closed as off-topic by a few people (me included) I had flagged it beforehand suggesting a move to "Code Review." Is it that all questions closed as off-topic go to Programmers?

How is that choice made?

Comment: I believe it depends on the distribution of close votes. I can only assume it was closed as `off-topic` -> Belongs on Progarmmers by several people (whether correctly or not).

Comment: You were the only one who did *not* vote to migrate to programmers.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to believe that somebody with 30k on SO actually believes "all questions closed as off-topic go to Programmers"

Comment: @MichaelMrozek lol I don't. I did not want it to go there. Thats what the whole question is about :-P

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA It wasn't a bad migration in my opinion.

Comment: @Anna - really?  You don't think that question was a better fit for CodeReview?

Comment: @AdamRackis I can see how it could go both ways, honestly. The general architecture/OOP use review would belong on Programmers. Code itself would be Code Review. The question reads conceptually enough to me that I don't think migrating to Programmers is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like the other 4 people voted as `off-topic -> belongs on Programmers`. Your final off-topic vote (actually, it wouldn't matter what you voted as at that point) closed the question and migrated it.

Migrations from Stack Overflow require four out of five voters to vote for the migration. Flagging has no effect on it except where it summons a moderator who migrates or closes the question.

All off-topic questions are certainly not suitable for nor migrated to Programmers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends only from who votes to close the question: If four users out of five votes to migrate, then the question is migrated; the destination is the one who got the most votes. There isn't a setting that automatically select *Programmers* as default migration path for Stack Exchange, which is just another migration path as others.

If you flagged it to be closed, you really voted to close the question (as you have the reputation to vote to close questions); if you flagged the question for moderation attention, no moderator has been involved in the migration (and therefore, none of the users who closed the question has seen your flag).