# Rethinking the migration process

Tags: discussion, migration

There are a handful of proposals on MSE aimed at changing how migration works, usually by expanding who can migrate what to where, and are rejected because more migration powers would mean more bad migrations (which is largely true). To me these suggestions appear to be merely chipping away at what I think is a much more fundamental problem.

## The Symptoms

I'm basing this question on the following premises (which my personal experience has borne out):

1. The only people qualified to judge whether a question should be closed or deleted on site X are users of site X.
2. The only people qualified to judge whether a question is on-topic on site Y and should be migrated there are users of site Y.
3. Most users of site Y are not moderating site X, so they don't get a chance to judge whether or not a question should be migrated to Y until after five site X users have voted to migrate it.
4. Whether a question should be closed or deleted on site X is not at all related to whether it is on-topic over on site Y. In particular, a question being "more on-topic" on site Y is never a valid reason on its own to close it on site X or migrate it to site Y.
5. Site Y being a "common" migration target for site X does not mean site X users are any better or worse at judging migrations to site Y.
6. More migrations get rejected than we would like, and a rejection rate generally does not go down without some kind of manual intervention to "educate users".
7. In practice, the safest way to do a migration seems to be bypassing the actual migration vote system in favor of asking site Y's chat room whether or not the question is any good.
8. When I do vote for migration the usual way, I often never find out whether the migration happened or whether it was well-received on site Y, so there's little to stop me from repeating any mistakes I might be making.

There are of course exceptions to these statements, such as the [couple of communities that actually do limited "cross-site moderation"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79408/you-are-being-watched-comments-of-interest). But that strikes me as the exception that proves the rule. Those communities wouldn't be cobbling together [cross-site moderation tools](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/51786/duga) if there wasn't a problem in need of fixing.

## The Problem

I believe this all boils down to the fact that **closing a question and migrating it are not the same thing, and the users qualified to make each of those decisions are on two different sites.**

## My Proposal

The two big changes that I personally think would solve these problems are:

1. **Separate the closing process from the migration process**
2. **Put the migration decision primarily in the hands of the target site**

Here's one rough outline of an idea for a concrete implementation. It'll almost certainly never happen, but it should at least clarify what I have in mind when I make those vague statements.

- In the Closing > Off-Topic dialog, remove the "This belongs on another site" section entirely, and instead add a "Nominate for Migration" checkbox that appears after an off-topic reason has been selected. If the user checks it, present them with some way of selecting a target site (which I believe should include all graduated and public beta sites, but let's not get hung up on that tangent). Nomination only requires one user.
- Once nominated for migration by site X, and closed on site X, the question appears either as a flag for site Y moderators to handle, or it goes into a "migration nominees" review queue on site Y where 3-5 high-rep users have to approve it. Either way, the actual migration decision is made solely by site Y users. If site Y approves, the migration "operation" is executed exactly as it is today. Downvotes get removed, the "Migrated from..." banner is applied, and so on.
- The site X user who originally made the nomination should receive an inbox notification when the migration is approved or rejected, so they get some kind of feedback. There should be no rep associated with this, though maybe a badge would be okay.

Ideally, a "nomination for migration" would be equivalent to politely asking "Does this belong on your site?" rather than the current system where we unilaterally declare "We've decided this belongs on your site. Here you go." and the other site has to appeal that decision. There would also be no need to actively educate users of site X if they get feedback automatically in their inbox, so reject rates should never stay high for an extended period of time like they do now.

---

Obviously any implementation of this would be a fairly huge change, and it's unlikely SE sees migration reform as a top priority right now, so it's pretty much guaranteed to get ignored. But I don't see any existing proposals like this on MSE, so it seems worth discussing at least.

Comment: This sounds like a very good idea, however only if the actual migration (once approved by enough Y users) is only done if *and only if* the question actually does get closed on site X. Maybe this is implied by your approach but I couldn't find it stated explicitly right now.

Comment: @ChristianRau I actually did not think of that, but now that you've pointed it out I agree with you. I tried to avoid putting in too many hypothetical details since I'm mostly interested in whether people agree with the general idea.

Comment: Sure, but that's a *big* difference. We don't really want a single X user and 5 Y users to snatch away a perfectly on-topic question, do we (and as long as it is only one X user, it still *is* a perfectly on-topic question as to the standards of SE's close-voting policies)?

Comment: @ChristianRau Hm, when you put it like that it does sound like that detail is a bit more important than most of the ones I deliberately left out. I'll edit it in.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167464/pipe-migrated-questions-to-the-review-queues-of-the-destination-site