# Binding voting for migration closures by high-rep users

Tags: feature-request, migration, privileges

If I'm a high-rep user on both SO and, e.g., stats.stackexchange, why not give executive rights when voting to close a question that clearly needs to be migrated? That is, no consensus needed -- once a sufficiently "experienced" user of *both* communities weighs in, voting can end.

(perhaps this feature does exist, and I simply haven't met the criteria yet; documentation would be helpful)

This is inspired by the analogous rights for gold badge users closing duplicates *within* SO.

Comment: Most people, regardless of reputation, don't understand migration. How does reputation on both sites equate to knowing whether it's appropriate to migrate at all?

Comment: This is a decent idea. Moderators have been asking for some version of this for years. However, I'm not sure the value the feature brings justifies the time the developers will need to implement it. Having tons of reputation in two sites with overlapping expertise is rare. Questions worthy of migration are even rarer. Remember, questions need to be spectacularly good to be migrated. Especially if it's only one person deciding. And questions asked on the wrong site, are almost always not that great. I doubt the feature will be used a lot. At least not correctly.

Comment: I see far to many questions migrated to SU from other websites that don’t pass the simplest quality checks, and those are moderators from those communities doing that, I can’t imag what a normal user would migrate

Comment: I don't think this is duplicate of [Suggest migration sites based on reputation at destination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253174). That other one does not mention the binding vote at all. Reopened.

Comment: @MaskedMan The first step in the process is knowing whether the question is even on topic on the current site at all. I have gotten dozens of flags for migration on questions that aren't off topic at all, people just think they'd be a "better fit". So, no... I'm really not OK with a single non-moderator user deciding "I'd really rather earn rep for this on TWP, so I'm going to migrate it".

Comment: I disagree with this request, because we have documented cases where even high-rep users don't know how the site works.

Answer (score 3):

No, for two reasons:

1. Too many people, including high-rep users, think "this would be better on another site" is a valid reason to migrate.  It's not; we only migrate questions that are *off-topic* where asked, not just to find them a "better" home.  As a moderator I see a lot of flags requesting migrations of on-topic questions; I am speaking for experience, not speculation.
2. Incorrect migrations are much harder to undo than incorrect dupe-hammers.  The user has been sent to another site, bounced migrations make a big mess with things getting locked, and it's just plain disruptive.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a fan of this proposal at all, and to explain why...

Let's look a bit closer at it.

1. A user with sufficient reputation (unknown amount) on two sites could migrate between them unilaterally.
2. This would only apply to the (up to) five selected migration targets.
3. This would exclude all beta sites (since they generally can't be migration targets).

I'm making the assumption in point two because, without it, this would be even more problematic than I already think it is. This would put those users on the same level as moderators, to a degree, though mods don't need any local reputation for migrations. Point three follows from point two as, with very few exceptions, there are no migration paths to or from beta sites.

While this would greatly limit the potential for damage as many sites don't actually have migration paths and those that do are limited to five, the current way migration works actually only requires three migration votes to move something, not five. You need two other users to vote to close the questions - for any other reason, but if three or more close votes on a question are migration votes, the question will be migrated...

And this fact already causes issues. Yes, those users often don't have local knowledge of a site to know whether something is on topic there or not, but many poor migrations still happen because of a few reasons:

#### The first and absolute rule of migration is to ask "Is this on topic *here*?"

As far as I'm aware, most users really don't remember this most of the time. In order to be considered for migration, a question must first be off topic on the site it was posted on. That's why it's in the close section under "off topic" close reasons.

As a moderator, I get requests to migrate questions to other sites all the time - these questions are *sometimes* on topic there, but they're rarely completely *off topic* on the site they were posted and they're often posted by very knowledgeable users from the site they're asking the post to be migrated to.

While some users don't realize their questions would be on topic in multiple places, many of them do and they intentionally ask their question where they chose to ask it. As such, we should respect their choice of where they asked the question unless it's actually off topic. Until users can prove that they understand this concept, unilateral migrations should be limited.

#### The second, more often remembered rule of migration is "don't migrate crap".

Even still, this rule is often forgotten. If a question is bad, it doesn't really matter if it's on topic somewhere else. If it's unclear or too broad or primarily opinion based, or lacking in any research, there's no reason to dump the question on another site just so it can be closed there and the migration rejected. You're much better off closing the question locally and encouraging the user to post the question on the other site than in trying to migrate it.

If the question is re-asked and then closed, it will stay on the new site, and the OP will be able to fix it to meet the standards of that site. This is much less confusing for the user, possibly new to the network, than having their existing question bounced back and forth and closed and opened and deleted and locked and... all of the stupid baggage that comes with migrations.

#### Potential for abuse.

Also, maybe I'm jaded, but I feel this could be pretty badly abused by some. A user with high reputation on two sites that have somewhat overlapping scopes and a default migration path between the two someone could say "I've rep-capped on this site already, so I'm going to migrate it to the other site where it's also on topic and then I can answer it there and keep earning reputation."

So, considering this, I can't support this proposal.

Comment: +1 for *Is this on topic here?*